# REST API wrapper class with Alamofire + Gloss

Tags: swift, api

I have come up with this structure to handle API calls using **Alamofire + Gloss**.

The multipart method I came up with was kind of in a hurry, it works but I think it could be done much better.

#### So this piece of code will...

1. Build a url and insert path parameters for **REST** design
2. Request to the server using **Alamofire**
3. Use generics to parse the response into a model conforming to `Gloss.Decodable`
4. Run response closures on the main thread

When using this structure it will look something like this:

```
API.someAPI(someParameter: "some-value").call(
    success: { status, response in
        // Do something with response
    },
    failed: { errorMessage in
        // Do something with error message
    },
    final: {
        // Do something when finished regarding of success or fail
    })
```

### The actual structure:

```
class API {
    static let host: Host = .test
    static let debug = true

    static var headers: [String: String] {
        return [
            "some-static-header": "Some static value"
        ]
    }

    enum Host: String {
        case test = "some://host.test"
        case live = "some://host.live"
    
        /** 
            Put parameters into path using /{id}/ syntax
            @param api Path to API
            @params parameters The key and values
        */
        func url(_ api: String, _ parameters: Dict = [:]) -> String {
            var api = api
            parameters.forEach { _ = api.replace("{\($0)}", with: "\($1)") }
            return "\(self.rawValue)...\(api)"
        }
    }

    static let someStaticURL = URL(string: "some/url")!
    static let someStaticUR2L = URL(string: "some/url2")!
}


// Extensions containing the API's
extension API {
    static func someApi(someParameter: String) -> Core<SomeGlossStruct> {
        let api = "some/api/{someParameter}"
        let url = host.url(api, parameters: ["someParameter", someParameter])
    
        let body = [
            "some": "data"
        ]
    
        return Core(method: .get, url: url, parameters: body, headers: headers)
    }
}


/// The Handler
struct Core<T: Decodable> {
    let request: DataRequest


    private func printRequest(parameters: Dict?) {
        if !API.debug { return }
    
        print()
        print("SEND", request, "|", request.request?.httpBody?.count ?? 0, "b", "|")
    
        if let headers = request.request?.allHTTPHeaderFields {
            print("Headers:", headers)
        }
    
        if let data = request.request?.httpBody {
            print("Body:", String(data)!)
        }
        else if let par = parameters {
            let a = par.map { "\($0.key)=\($0.value)" }
            print("Parameters:", a.joined(by: "&"))
        }
    
        print()
    }

    init(method: HTTPMethod, url: URLConvertible, parameters: Dict? = nil, headers: [String: String]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default) {
        request = Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
    
        printRequest(parameters: parameters)
    }


    /// Upload multipart with ex: Image and String parameters in body
    static func upload(method: HTTPMethod, url: URLConvertible, headers: [String: String]? = nil, buildForm: @escaping (Alamofire.MultipartFormData)->(), response: @escaping (Int, T)->()) {
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: buildForm, usingThreshold: 0, to: url, method: method, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let request, _, _): Core(uploadRequest: request).call(success: response)
                case .failure(let error): print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
    
    init(uploadRequest: UploadRequest) {
        request = uploadRequest
    
        printRequest(parameters: nil)
    }




    func call(success: @escaping (Int, T)->(), failed: ((String)->())? = nil, final: Closure? = nil) {
        request.responseJSON { response in
            if API.debug {
                print()
                print("RECEIVED", self.request, "|", Int(response.timeline.totalDuration * 1000), "ms", "|", response.data?.count ?? 0, "b", "|")
                if let data = response.data, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(string.replaced("\\", with: ""))
                }
                print()
            }
        
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    guard
                        let json = value as? JSON,
                        let data = T(json: json)
                    else {
                        failed?("Parsing error")
                        break
                    }
                    success(response.response!.statusCode, data)
            
                case .failure(let error):
                    failed?(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        
            final?()
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about it? Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome, like performance, readability, names etc.